# Bifunctor: Vector space of linear transformations betw vector spaces as bifunctor

Tags: ct.category-theory

Good day,
I'm really gut stuck with the understanding of the following:

$(E,V) \mapsto L(E,V)$  is the functor in two variables, countravariant in the first one and covariant in the second.

I'm struggle to understand why it's contravariant in the first variable.

I'm trying to write this down explicitely like:
$\lambda: E^{op} \times V \to L(E,V)$  is a bifunctor, such that for each pair of objects $<e^{op},v>$ it assigns an object $\tau \in L(E,V)$ -  a linear transformation bewteen $e^{op}$ and $v$, and to each arrow $<f^{op},g> \in E \times V$ a composition (?) $ \tau_1 \circ \tau_2 \in  Hom(L(E,V))$

But I still can't see why this functor inverses arrows exactly for the first argument?

Comment: Definitely not a research-level question.

Comment: How is $E$ a category? Shouldn't you be thinking of $E$ as an object in the category of vector spaces and linear maps.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/faq

Comment: A better place for this question would be http://math.stackexchange.com/, but I'd suggest thinking about Michael Murray's comment and rewriting your question before posting it there.  

Answer (score 1):

$L(f,g)(h) = g\circ h\circ f: E_0\to E_1 \to V_1\to V_0$, thus
$L(f,g): L(E_1,V_1)\to L(E_0,V_0)$ where $f:E_0\to E_1$ and $g:V_1\to V_0$.